# Displaying horizontal recyclerview along with images and text in expandable listview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview, expandablerecyclerview

[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74a1z.png)

Hi i want to display the horizontal recycler view with the images below the text view inside an expandable listview as shown in the image,how can i achieve this please help me,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Horizontal RecyeclerView & Specify LayoutManager to be Horizantal

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView HorizontalRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewId);
HorizontalRV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```